# Would my answers to this quantifier question also be correct?

Tags: quantifiers

Translate these statements into English, where R(x) is “x is a rabbit” and H(x) is
“x hops”, and the domain consists of all animals.

$$(a) ∀xR(x) → H(x)$$

$$(b) ∀xR(x) ∧ H(x)$$

$$(c) ∃xR(x) → H(x)$$

$$(d) ∃xR(x) ∧ H(x)$$

The answers to these were the following:

(a) Every rabbit hops.

(b) All animals are rabbits and they all hop.

(c) There is an animal such that if it is a rabbit then it hops.

(d) There is a hopping rabbit.

***Are my answers also correct?:***

(a) For all x, if x is a rabbit, then x hops

(b) For all x, x is a rabbit and x hops

(c) There exists an x, if x is a rabbit then it hops

(d) There exists an x, where x is a rabbit and it hops

Edit: if they aren't correct, why not?

Comment: $ \exists x $ means, there exists At Least one element $ x $

Comment: $x$ was not said to be an animal. for (b) for example, "everything is a hopping rabbit"

Comment: so if ∃x means there exists at least one element x, then why is the answer to (d) there is a hopping rabbit and not there is at least one hopping rabbit? @hamam_Abdallah

Comment: it says in the question that the domain are animals @DavidP

Comment: oops. but yes, "there is a" and "there exists at least one" are the same.

Comment: so are my answers correct? @DavidP

Comment: The question was to write them in English, i.e "Natural English language".   It is not natural English language to define variables then use the variables in a sentence! (IMO)